# Is there a way to tell if a Corda node goes down?

Tags: corda

I have an application connected to a Corda node using CordaRPC. If I stop the Corda node, I can't see a good way to detect that from my app. Eventually, if I try to call an RPC function, I get an error. Is there any low-level way to detect a lost connection?

Answer (score 0):

As of Corda 3.1, no. There is no exposed API to detect a lost connection.